# Reading Azure Sessions from AZ CLI

Tags: azure-cli

I am using AZ CLI to try to see how many sessions my user account has open. I figured it would be a subcommand under `az account` but I can't find it. How can I see all active sessions?

Answer (score -1):

> Reading Azure Sessions from AZ CLI:

The following methods can be used to read user login session information as well as how many sessions the user has.

1. You can use [`--query user`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/query-user#syntax) under `az account` Cli command to get user sessions as shown:

```bash
$accounts_info = az account show --query user.name --output table
$accounts_info
```

***Output:***

[image]

If a session/user count is required, the count operator should be used for the final output.

`$accounts_info.count`

[image]

2. To get complete log information of session activities, Use below command.

```bash
Get-AzLog
```

[image]

3. You can also obtain sessions using `az account --query session`.

Use [query_session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/query-session#syntax) as mentioned here:

```bash
az account show --query session.name
```

Comment: I don't beleive any of your suggestions are valid:
1) Account Show returns subscription information of the user (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-show).
This is different from a session. For example, I should have two sessions open since I am using the portal website and az cli.
2) Get-AzLog is a powershell command and we are talking about AZ CLI
3) az account show --query session.name filters the subscription data for a session objects name, but the subscription data does not contain a session object.

Comment: Checking again.

Comment: [Get a temporary session](https://winsmarts.com/get-a-temporary-session-in-azure-cli-90fb5d2df290):- Is this works for you?

Comment: no it doesn't work for me.